# d3.js v4 how to set brush programmatically

Tags: d3.js, brush

I am building a version of this parallel coordinate view in d3.js v4.
https://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/05a5b0897a48890133beb59c815bd953

In my example I have a predefined  selection (in the form of a [min,max] array that I would like to set programatically as a brush in one or more of the axes, after the plot has loaded. But I cannot seem to find a way to do it. Most examples I found on setting a brush from code are using d3 v3 and use setting extent but that does not work anymore in v4 it seems.

can someone give me some tips and a simple example hot to do this in this case (so with multiple axes and brushes active) ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Select your brush group and call `brush.move`, then also pass an array with the start and end coordinates. Your brush move event will then take care of the rest.

```js
d3.select(".brush").call(brush.move, [[startX, endX], [startY, endY]]);
```

Comment: I know I should use move, but my problem is to access the right objects. In my OP example code, what would be the brushGroup?

Comment: It looks like they use `svg.selectAll(".axis .brush")` to select the brush. I'll update my answer to be more specific

Comment: So I modified the example to make it run locally (pull all files to local folder and load from there). That works, next I added a link to run my setbrush function

<a href="#" onclick="setbrush()">click</a>..

and I defined this setbrush function

function setbrush(){
 var selection = d3.select(".axis .brush");
 selection.call(brush.move, [[10,10], [100,200]]);
 }

and put it as the very bottom function in the source
but when called the function gives an error: ReferenceError: brush is not defined

Comment: I would bind the click event using d3 as well. `<a id='setBrush'></a> d3.select("#setBrush").on("click", function(){func here})`