# d3.js: synchronous selection across multiple charts

Tags: d3.js

How do I have to handle the selection when I want to archive a synchronous selection on multiple charts? When I make a selection the exactly same selection should be shown on other charts too.

I added you a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Lnz7c36e/19/) which was made in dc.js.

My code at the moment looks like:

```js
var signalData = {
      signal1: {
        name: "signal1",
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 7, 4, 6],
      },
      signal2: {
        name: "signal2",
        data: [6, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 5, 7, 1],
      },
      signal3: {
        name: "signal3",
        data: [9, 5, 12, 3, 8, 4, 8, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 8, 6, 8, 5, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1],
      },
    }

    var margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 50
    };
    var width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(Object.keys(signalData), d => signalData[d].data.length)]) // input
      .range([0, width]); // output

    var brushXScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(Object.keys(signalData), d => signalData[d].data.length)]) // input
      .range([0, width]); // output

    var brush = d3.brushX().extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width - margin.right, height],
    ]).on("brush", brushed);

    function brushed(d) {
      var selectionPx = d3.brushSelection(this); // === [lower, upper] in pixels

      // transform from pixels to x-values
      var selectionX = [xScale.invert(selectionPx[0]), xScale.invert(selectionPx[1])];

      // set x scale domain, then redraw the lines
      brushXScale.domain(selectionX);

      for (var signal in signalData) {
        updateChart(
          signalData[signal].data,
          signalData[signal].name
        );
      }
    }

    //Generate the brush focus chart
    generateMinimap(signalData.signal1.data);
    //Generate charts dynamically as often as i have signals
    for (var signal in this.signalData) {
      generateChart(
        signalData[signal].data,
        signalData[signal].name
      );
    }

    // This function is for the one time preparations
    function generateChart(data, name) {
      var svg = d3
        .select("#" + name)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

      svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "blue");

      updateChart(data, name);
    }

    // This function needs to be called to update the already prepared chart
    function updateChart(data, name) {
      var svg = d3.select("#" + name + " svg");

      var yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // input
        .range([height, 0]); // output

      var line = d3
        .line()
        .x((d, i) => brushXScale(i))
        .y((d) => yScale(d));
      console.log(line([1, 2, 3, 4]));

      svg.select(".x.axis")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(brushXScale));

      svg.select(".y.axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

      svg
        .select(".line")
        .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
        .attr("d", line) // 11. Calls the line generator
    }

    function generateMinimap(data) {
      var yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // input
        .range([height, 0]); // output

      var line = d3
        .line()
        .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
        .y((d) => yScale(d));

      var svg = d3
        .select("#minimap")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      svg.append("g").call(brush);

      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

      svg
        .append("path")
        .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
        .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
        .attr("d", line) // 11. Calls the line generator
        .attr("fill-opacity", "0.17")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("stroke", "blue");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <div id="minimap"></div>
  <!-- In the original project these divs are not 
    static and get generated with v-for as many times as 
    i have a signal in signalData -->
  <div id="signal1"></div>
  <div id="signal2"></div>
  <div id="signal3"></div>
```

**Important to know** the charts are getting rendered dynamically and the amount of charts can be more or less!

I have tried to get the data out of the selection and add it to the other ones, but I didn't came to a result.

Comment: What do you mean by a "selection"? Is it a single point, a subset, like a brush, or something else? Can you maybe find an online showcase of what it should look like? Only with one chart is fine, just to give us an idea what you mean

Comment: I wanto to do a range selection with the brush tool. You can open the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Lnz7c36e/19/) I included in the question. The example is written in dc.js. I want the exact same functionality wich you can see in the example.

Comment: In the JSFiddle, I see a crossfilter being applied. So you want that people zoom in using the `minimap` and then also have the same behaviour on the other charts, only then it doesn't zoom, it just highlights?

Comment: Yes i think you git it. The typical workflow of the user with the charts would be: 
1. Take a look at the charts
2. zoom into all of the charts with the `minimap`
3. make a selection in one of the charts (out of the `minimap` chart because this is only used to zoom).
4. Select a "datarange" with the brush toll in one of the charts. The same brush selection should be added automatically on to the other charts (out of the `minimap`).
5. And in best case console log all selections.

I hope that makes a bit more clear what i want to do.

Comment: And i as far as i know the attached crossfilter in the jsfiddle has nothing to do with the synchronous brush selection functionality

Comment: Please remember that we are all volunteering our own time to help the community

Comment: Yes Im sorry. If you have news just let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/click-to-recenter-brush), you can [call `brush` programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49177283/5015356).

This way, every instance gets the same highlighting. I created a new brush `selectBrush` that calls all other brush containers and applies the same brush there.

```js
var signalData = {
  signal1: {
    name: "signal1",
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 7, 4, 6],
  },
  signal2: {
    name: "signal2",
    data: [6, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 5, 7, 1],
  },
  signal3: {
    name: "signal3",
    data: [9, 5, 12, 3, 8, 4, 8, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 8, 6, 8, 5, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1],
  },
};

var margin = {
  top: 10,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 50,
};
var width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(Object.keys(signalData), d => signalData[d].data.length)]) // input
  .range([0, width]); // output

var brushXScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(Object.keys(signalData), d => signalData[d].data.length)]) // input
  .range([0, width]); // output

var zoomBrush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width - margin.right, height],
  ])
  .on("brush", zoomBrushed);

var selectBrush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width - margin.right, height],
  ])
  .on("brush", selectBrushed);

function zoomBrushed() {
  var selectionPx = d3.brushSelection(this); // === [lower, upper] in pixels

  // transform from pixels to x-values
  var selectionX = [xScale.invert(selectionPx[0]), xScale.invert(selectionPx[1])];

  // set x scale domain, then redraw the lines
  brushXScale.domain(selectionX);

  for(var signal in signalData) {
    updateChart(
      signalData[signal].data,
      signalData[signal].name,
    );
  }
}

function selectBrushed() {
  var selectionPx = d3.brushSelection(this); // === [lower, upper] in pixels

  selectBrush.on("brush", null);
  // This is the starts-with selector (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)
  d3.selectAll("div[id^=signal] svg .brushcontainer")
    .call(selectBrush.move, selectionPx);
  selectBrush.on("brush", selectBrushed);
}

//Generate the brush focus chart
generateMinimap(signalData.signal1.data);
//Generate charts dynamically as often as i have signals
for(var signal in this.signalData) {
  generateChart(
    signalData[signal].data,
    signalData[signal].name,
  );
}

// This function is for the one time preparations
function generateChart(data, name) {
  var svg = d3
    .select("#" + name)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "brushcontainer")
    .call(selectBrush);
  
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");

  svg
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "blue");

  updateChart(data, name);
}

// This function needs to be called to update the already prepared chart
function updateChart(data, name) {
  var svg = d3.select("#" + name + " svg");

  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // input
    .range([height, 0]); // output

  var line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d, i) => brushXScale(i))
    .y((d) => yScale(d));

  svg.select(".x.axis")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(brushXScale));

  svg.select(".y.axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

  svg
    .select(".line")
    .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
    .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator
}

function generateMinimap(data) {
  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // input
    .range([height, 0]); // output

  var line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
    .y((d) => yScale(d));

  var svg = d3
    .select("#minimap")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
    .call(zoomBrush);

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

  svg
    .append("path")
    .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("d", line) // 11. Calls the line generator
    .attr("fill-opacity", "0.17")
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("stroke", "blue");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="minimap"></div>
<!-- In the original project these divs are not 
    static and get generated with v-for as many times as 
    i have a signal in signalData -->
<div id="signal1"></div>
<div id="signal2"></div>
<div id="signal3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to also delete all selections synchronously when i click outside of one of the 3 brush selections?

Comment: Yes, see the comment thread in your other question. You should be able to figure this out using that example and this answer

Comment: What does the `^` mean in `div[id^=signal]`?

Comment: CSS class starts with. There is a link in the comment immediately above it.

Comment: Is there a way to console.log the selections of all 3 charts after you created a selection on one chart?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: In the end version of the app the user can select a range in the chart with the brush selection. And with the synchronous selection you automatically selected that range on all charts (that is what we have now). Now i want to console.log the selected data of the selected range from all charts.

Comment: I want to get the data out of the selections in a console.log