# Add rangeSelector to linechart?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, linechart

I want to add rangeSelector  to this linechart https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

[image: current output]

[image: expected output with the rangeSelector]

First image : current output
second image : expected output with the range selector

I want to add this rangeselector to zoom on "last year", "last month" or "last week" or display "all" period

The version used of d3.js is  V4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [d3.js v4 how to set brush programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169014/d3-js-v4-how-to-set-brush-programmatically)

Comment: hello thank you for your response, no , i want to add button that select the period , when we click on week it edit the brush to select the last week

Comment: Hi... yes that question and answer covers how to set the brush in code (for d3 v4). I understand that's what you want the button to do e.g. select 'last year' and Jan 1 to Dec 31 2020 is the brush selection... So you set the button event handler code to do that operation.

Comment: add your code what you tried so far